# file.copy not working when called inside function

Tags: r

I'm trying to do a standardized directory setup through a function call. Inside this function I'm using two `file.copy` calls to copy some files from a selfmade package into the working directory of a project.

If I run the code line by line, everything is working fine but if I run the whole function, only the directories get created, but no files get copied. Unfortunately the function does not throw any error, so I really do not understand whats going on or where to start troubleshooting.

Maybe one of you guys can give me a hint where to find the solution.

abstract (non working) example:

```
dir_setup <- function() {

  # list directories which shall be created
  dir_names <- c("dir1", "dir2", "dir3", "dir4")

  # create directories
  lapply(dir_names, function(x){dir.create(path = paste(getwd(), x, sep = '/'))})

  # get path of package library
  lib_path <- .libPaths()

  # shorten list to vector of length 1
  if (length(lib_path) > 1) lib_path = lib_path[1]

  # list files in source
  files <- list.files(paste0(lib_path, "/package/files/dir1"), full.names = TRUE)

  # copy resource files from package directory to working directory
  file.copy(files, paste(getwd(), "dir1", sep = '/'), overwrite = TRUE)

  # list more files
  files2 <- list.files(paste0(lib_path, "/package/files/dir2"), full.names = TRUE)

  # copy more files from package directory to working directory
  file.copy(files2, paste(getwd(), "dir2", sep = '/'), overwrite = TRUE)

}
```

Comment: I suppose calling the `file.copy()` function in a loop will solve the problem?

Comment: may worth a try. But why does the proceduere work when called one after one in a script and not when called through a function? There has to be a technical reason for this behaviour?

Comment: The reason is that the functions providing low-level interface to the computer filesystem are not vectorized, what makes a complete sense I think...

Comment: Also, maybe try `file.path` instead of `paste` to build up paths to files.